# Extracting a URL with XPath from XML

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to extract the second link under the description tag. I have written the following code, but it looks really messy with freads and substrings (just to get it to work). Is there any cleaner way to accomplish this?

[image: XML Extract]

> magic(Url)->
>
> Tag = ".xml",
>
> inets:start(),
>
> { ok, {Status, Headers, Body }} = httpc:request(Url ++ Tag),
>
> { Xml, Rest } = xmerl_scan:string(Body),
>
> {xmlObj , string , A } = xmerl_xpath:string("substring-after(substring-after(substring->before(//channel/item/description[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGXJL.png)], '\">[link]') , 'br') , 'href=')", Xml),
>
> {ok,_,B} = io_lib:fread("~6s" , A),
>
> string:sub_string(B,1,string:len(B)-1).

Comment: could you post an url from which you get xml?

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/erlang/comments/y62wf/how_to_use_ranch/.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but you may use such xpaths
`//channel/item/description[1]/text()[16]` and `//channel/item/description[1]/text()[24]`

extracted strings contains urls + quotes at the beginning, so you may use list matching syntax to cut off quotation marks: `[_|Url] = ...`

So use this: `[{_,_,_,_,[_|U1],_}] = xmerl_xpath:string("//channel/item/description[1]/text()[16]", Xml).` to bind U1 with first url.

Test in shell:

```
11> [{_,_,_,_,[_|U1],_}] = xmerl_xpath:string("//channel/item/description[1]/text()[16]", Xml). 
[{xmlText,[{description,5},{item,5},{channel,1},{rss,1}],
          16,[],"\"http://www.reddit.com/user/escaped_reddit",text}]
12> 
12> U1.
"http://www.reddit.com/user/escaped_reddit"
13> 
13> 
13> [{_,_,_,_,[_|U2],_}] = xmerl_xpath:string("//channel/item/description[1]/text()[24]", Xml). 
[{xmlText,[{description,5},{item,5},{channel,1},{rss,1}],
          24,[],
          "\"http://www.reddit.com/r/erlang/comments/y62wf/how_to_use_ranch/",
          text}]
14> 
14> U2.
"http://www.reddit.com/r/erlang/comments/y62wf/how_to_use_ranch/"
```

Comment: Wow! That is exactly what I was looking for. XPath seems to me quite confusing, and this solutions makes total sense! Thanks!